# Where can I get libssh for windows without vcpkg?

Tags: c++, eclipse, libssh

I am trying to get ssh library from [here](https://www.libssh.org/get-it/) but i am using Eclipse as IDE and i am not able to use vcpkg.
Can anyone help me with some information.

Comment: ***Can anyone help me with a tutorial?*** A tutorial is an off-topic request at StackOverflow. See #4 here: [https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I believe vcpkg now has support for mingw although I have not tested that, I primarily use Visual Studio 2019 on windows for my development.

Comment: I can't use VS i have only Eclipse. 
I tried to run in powershell vcpkg and I got error because I don't have visual studio installed.

Comment: I assume you are using `mingw` as your compiler. `eclipse` being the IDE really is not the issue its your choice of compiler.

Comment: Have you tried building it yourself or using Conan?

Comment: *Why* aren't you able to use `vcpkg`?